# SELECT query with WHERE returns all rows when column name and value are equal

Tags: mysql, select

I am confused by how my `SELECT` query is behaving. Accidentally I read the header row of a *.csv* file into my table. This means there is now one row in the table which has the column values in each corresponding column.

But a `SELECT` like this

```
select * from `mytablename` where segmentering=`segmentering`;
```

Returns all the rows in the table.

Why is MySQL ignoring the condition?

Comment: It isn't `segmentering` is enclosed in backticks which means the column is being compared to itself.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `'segmentering'` not with back tick(``)

```
select * from `mytablename` where segmentering='segmentering'
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you use single quote **`** object identifier for strings.
instead of it use normal single quote:

```
select * from `mytablename` where segmentering='segmentering';
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with you are adding ``` back quotes(``) ``` with the value field. Back quote will be used for specifying column or table names. It should not be used with the value.

Try using,

```
select * from `mytablename` where `segmentering`='segmentering';
```

OR

```
select * from `mytablename` where segmentering='segmentering';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from `mytablename` where segmentering='segmentering';
```

Remove `` and replace '';

I hope it will work for you